# Laravel, Docker, AWS SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = w

Tags: php, laravel, database, amazon-web-services, docker

I am trying to deploy my laravel application on docker in aws. On my windows computer it works perfectly but on my aws machine it doesn't.
I don't know if I have to give any more permissions, or some specific configuration.
I have also created the ingress rules in the security group of the aws instance, for the corresponding ports 8000, 8080, 3306 to open them.

When I execute the "docker-compose up -d" command on my windows machine, it creates the 3 containers, no container is closed and it executes the commands put in the "command" section of the docker-compose.yml "php artisan migrate" and "php artisan db:seed" they work without any problem.
I have tried to put localhost DB_HOST as some users say, but obviously it does not work

But when I do the same steps on my AWS machine, the myapp container closes and gives me the following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
myapp_1       |
myapp_1       |   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = wallamotop and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
myapp_1       |
myapp_1       |   at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:793
myapp_1       |     789▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
myapp_1       |     790▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
myapp_1       |     791▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
myapp_1       |     792▕         catch (Exception $e) {
myapp_1       |   ➜ 793▕             throw new QueryException(
myapp_1       |     794▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
myapp_1       |     795▕             );
myapp_1       |     796▕         }
myapp_1       |     797▕     }
myapp_1       |
myapp_1       |       +38 vendor frames
myapp_1       |
myapp_1       |   39  artisan:37
myapp_1       |       Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
myapp_1       |
wallamotop_myapp_1 exited with code 1
```

.env archive:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:sKPVZblHmpBF0G5Jgax5aucPYYfm+GPPGZn6DgePymw=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://proyecto.test

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mariadb
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=wallamotop
DB_USERNAME=daniel
DB_PASSWORD=
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  mariadb:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.6
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_USER=daniel
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=wallamotop # Cambio realizado aquí

  myapp:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/laravel:10
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mariadb
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_USERNAME=root
      - DB_DATABASE=wallamotop # Cambio realizado aquí
    volumes:
      - './:/app'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb

    command: bash -c "php artisan migrate && php artisan db:seed"

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - mariadb:db
    ports:
      - '8080:80' 
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=mariadb
      - MYSQL_USER=daniel
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
```

config/database.php:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'mariadb'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'wallamotop'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'daniel'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],
```

Does anyone know how to solve the "myapp" container from closing and permit me execute the php artisan migrate commands and php artisan db:seed command please?

Comment: It might be worth removing the `command` and ssh onto the AWS server to try to debug the docker connection/environment details - double check your .env is loaded onto the server correctly for instance